# Mockery mock class that returns another mocked class

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit, mockery

I have a class

```
<?php

class Cards
{
    public function __construct($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function add($card) {
        // Make API call
        return true;
    }
}
```

and another class that returns the Cards class

```
<?php

class Payment
{
    public function cards() {
        return new Cards('1');
    }
}
```

And I cannot seem to figure out how to mock Payment so it returns a mocked Cards. Basically I want to

Mock Payment so it returns a mocked Cards that would allow a function like

```
function() {
    $vault = new Payment;
    $cards = $vault->cards();

    if ($cards->add()) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

can be mocked and tested without making API calls to the payment processor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to instantiate the `Card` class using the `new` keyword. This makes it (almost) impossible to mock it. You can use a couple of different techniques to replace the `new` keyword, the easiest would be to pass an instance into the `Payment` constructor or directly into the method.